# Absolutely integrable implies almost surely finite

Tags: probability

If $X$ is absolutely integrable, i.e., $\mathbb {E}\vert X \vert<\infty$, I want to show that $X$ is almost surely finite, i.e., $\mathbb {P}(\vert X\vert<\infty)=1$. For now, I have the following:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {E}\vert X\vert=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb {P}(\vert X\vert\geq u)\, du
\end{align*}

I wonder how to argue based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $P(|X| = \infty) = c > 0$. Thus for all $u \ge 0$ we have  $P(|X| > u) \ge P(|X| = \infty) = c$. Thus $\infty > E|X| = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X|\ge u)du \ge \int_{0}^{\infty} c du =\infty$. It's contradiction.